# What is the rolling thing (in real world, if exist) that Moriko used to clean the floor?

Tags: recovery-of-an-mmo-junkie

I saw Moriko Morioka cleaning the floor with the rolling thing.

[image: rolling1]

[image: rolling2]

But I have never seen that thing in real life that use for cleaning. Actually, I have seen the rolling thing like that, but it was used to paint the wall (people dip into paint and roll on the wall).

I wonder what is that thing in real life. Does it exist?

Comment: It could be a [lint remover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_remover).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a lint remover.

Comment: FYI: in Japanese it is usually called [korokoro](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8A%E3%83%BC&rlz=1C1AVNE_enJP724JP725&sxsrf=AOaemvLGdWRDzXzF9PnengEjSG8Xa88euw:1642216793445&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJzPek5rL1AhVQr1YBHQgiBa8Q_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1416&bih=864&dpr=1.1), which is a onomatopoeia for rolling.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments, **it is a [lint remover/roller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_remover)**. In Japan, the tool is usually called [COLOCOLO](https://www.nitoms.com/en/colocolo/) (コロコロ, *korokoro*, which is also [an onomatopoeic word for rolling](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AD)), a [generic term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_distinctiveness#Generic_terms) for "adhesive (carpet) cleaner/roller".

The series also [had some official merchandise](https://twitter.com/netoju_anime/status/953563458129215489), including Moriko's Cleaner.

> [image]

---

References:

- [Japanese live-commentary tweets for episode 3](http://anicobin.ldblog.jp/archives/52315068.html)
- [English translation of COLOCOLO](https://eigojin.com/2020/12/20/korokoro/) (Japanese)